# Python, Dict to CSV: is there a faster way to do it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, csv

I've written a simple method to write a dictionary to a CSV.

It works well but I've wondering if it can be improved in terms of speeds (writing a CSV of 1000 rows takes 6 secs in my tests).

My question is: **how to improve the speed of this code?** (if possible)

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

```
def fast_writer(self, f_name, text_dict):
    try:
        start = timer()
        # Windows
        if os.name == "nt":
            with open(f_name, 'w', newline='') as self._csv_file:
                self._writer = csv.writer(self._csv_file)
                for self._key, self._value in text_dict.items():
                    self._writer.writerow([self._key, self._value])

        # Unix/Linux
        else:
            with open(f_name, 'w') as self._csv_file:
                self._writer = csv.writer(self._csv_file)
                for self._key, self._value in text_dict.items():
                    self._writer.writerow([self._key, self._value])

        end = timer()
        print("[FastWriter_time] ", end - start)
    except BaseException:
        print("[ERROR] Unable to write file on disk. Exit...")
        sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're really just looking for a faster way to do this, `pandas` has such methods built-in, and pretty well optimized! Take the following code for example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# This is just to generate a dictionary with 1000 values:
data_dict = {'value':[i for i in np.random.randn(1000)]}

# This is to translate dict to dataframe, and then same it
df = pd.DataFrame(data_dict)
df.to_csv('test.csv')
```

Takes about 0.008 seconds to write the dictionary to a dataframe *and* write the dataframe to a csv on my machine

Comment: At least on my machine the plain Python way is faster than this. Probably due to the overhead of reading the data in to the dataframe first.

Comment: I guess in the end it will be limited by disk write speed, anyways.

Comment: Just checking - Isn't that data_dict only a single row?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use `pandas`, get rid of all those variables being stored in `self` and make them local variables:

```
def fast_writer(self, f_name, text_dict):
    try:
        start = timer()
        newline = '' if os.name == "nt" else None
        with open(f_name, 'w', newline=newline) as csv_file:
            writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
            writer.writerows(text_dict.items())
        end = timer()
        print("[FastWriter_time] ", end - start)
    except BaseException as e:
        print("[ERROR] Unable to write file on disk. Exit...")
        print(e)
        sys.exit()
```

Also, use `writer.writerows` to write multiple rows at once.

On my machine this is faster than the `pandas` method, using the test data as defined by [@sacul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6671176/sacul) in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49112389/4042267):

```
In [6]: %timeit fast_writer("test.csv", data_dict)
1.59 ms ± 62.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [10]: %timeit fast_writer_pd("test.csv", data_dict)
3.97 ms ± 61.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Writer` object already has a method for writing a list of rows to the file; you don't need to iterate explicitly.

```
def fast_writer(self, f_name, text_dict):
    try:
        start = timer()

        with open(f_name, 'w', newline=None) as csv_file:
            writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
            writer.writerows(text_dict.items())

        end = timer()
        print("[FastWriter_time] ", end - start)
    except Exception:
        print("[ERROR] Unable to write file on disk. Exit...")
        sys.exit()
```

A few comments:

1. You don't need to sniff the operating system; `newline=None` uses the underlying system default.
2. If you are going to reallocate `self._writer` and `self._csv_file` on every call, they probably don't have to be instance attributes; they can just be local variables: `writer = csv.writer(csv_file)`.
3. `BaseException` is far too broad; it's no better than a bare `except` statement. Use `Exception`, but consider only catching `IOError` and `OSError` instead. Other exceptions may indicate bugs in your code, not legitimate IO errors.